# React Flask Code change not getting reflected on deployed Heroku application

Tags: python, html, reactjs, flask, heroku

I have deployed my React Flask application and the initial version works fine. However, I've made a few additional changes in my code and though the changes are getting reflected in my localhost, they do not seem to be getting reflected in the Heroku deployed application.

I ran the following commands to push code to heroku:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Heroku Deploy"
git push heroku master
```

Am I missing something to update code on heroku? I have also tried deleting the application and creating a new application again and then pushing the code. But it keeps showing my initial state of application during my 1st commit.

Comment: Did you try to add remote of your app with this one: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#for-an-existing-heroku-app

Comment: I had added the remote when I had created the application but I hadn't tried entering that command before pushing the changed code to heroku. I'll definitely try running that. Currently, I'm trying a method of deleting my build folder and then using command 'npm run build' to create that build folder again and then pushing it to Heroku. Let's see if either of these works. The pushing takes around 15 mins so it's quite a lengthy process.

Comment: It still isn't working. I tried what you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I deleted my application and then created a new one and modified the name slightly which is now showing the correct changes on Heroku. Earlier, I had also tried deleting it and creating a new application with the same name as the previous one but it that too wasn't showing the new changes so I tried changing the name of the application and that seemed to have done the trick. There could be a glitch on Heroku.